# Routes with guards do not work in server side rendering

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing an angular application, using universal angular (SSR).

the problem is occurring in which the routes that have guards (canLoad or canActivate, in this case) do not start the application, there is no response and it ends in a "Gateway Time-out" by nginx.

Routes that do not contain guards initiate the application perfectly.

Any idea why this may be happening?

**app.routes.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: 'administracion',
        canLoad: [IsAdminGuard],
        loadChildren: 'app/module-admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: 'app/module-page/page.module#PageModule'
    }
], { 
    useHash: false,
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
  })],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [IsAdminGuard]
```

})

**app.server.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: 'administracion',
        loadChildren: 'app/module-admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
        canLoad: [IsAdminGuard]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: 'app/module-page/page.module#PageModule'
    }
], { 
    useHash: false,
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
  })],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [IsAdminGuard]
```

})

**app.browser.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'frontend'}),
    AppModule,
]
```

})

**is-admin.guard.ts**

```
constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    private _userService: UserService,
    private router: Router
) {}

canLoad(): Promise<boolean> {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
            this._userService.isAdmin().toPromise().then(
                (response) => {
                    if (response) {
                        resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        this.router.navigate(['/']);
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                    resolve(false);
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start with checking router events, sth like this:
`constructor(private router: Router) {}`,
`this.router.events.pipe(tap(event => console.log(event)).subscribe();`
Pls check what is logged and post it here

Comment: Sorry, I understand english only. Would it be possible to translate to english?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but those who might bump into this. While upgrading an old project (where this issue was not present) we needed for function that was called in our guard, to return `null` if the platform is not browser:

```ts
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  let url: string = state.url;
  return this.checkLogin(url);
}

checkLogin(url: string) {
  if (this.authService.hasValidToken()) {
    return true;
  }
  if (this.authService.hasValidToken() === false) {
    // do stuff 
  }
  this.router.navigate(['']);
  return false;
}
```

Then the `hasValidToken()` function:

```ts
hasValidToken(): boolean {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    // do stuff, return true or false
  }
  return null; // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> needed to add this!
}
```

Comment: Seems right. Let me try this today. Thanks